# Conflict between ajax callback and jQuery UI dialog

Tags: 7, ajax, javascript, forms

I have a button that triggers an AJAX callback with the form api like so :

```
$form['show_modal'] = array(
 '#type' => 'submit',   
 '#value' => t('Some crazy text'),
 '#ajax' => array(
     'callback' => 'myCallback',
     'wrapper' => 'myWrapper',      
 ),
 '#suffix' => '</div>',
);
```

I then do some stuff and return my new form and display it (working).

```
 return $form['myNewForm'];
```

I want to display it in a custom jQueryUI dialog, 
but when I do that my AJAX callback doesn't work anymore ...

```
 //On click, open modal
 $('#showModale').click(function(){$('#myWrapper').dialog("open");});
 //Modal itself
 $("#myWrapper").dialog({
  autoOpen: false,
  show: {
    effect: "blind",
    duration: 300
  },
  hide: {
    effect: "blind",
    duration: 300
  },
  height: 400,
  width: 1000,
  modal: true,
  resizable: false,
  draggable: false,
});
```

Any ideas about it ?

Comment: Your post is vague. You want to post $form['myNewForm'] in the modal dialog?

Comment: Where is your  $form['myNewForm'] code?

Comment: My code is pretty long so I made a similar example.
The form is correctly returned, but I think the modal is not working properly with with my wrapper for an unknown reason.
I have a second modal who works properly (but filled via an external JS) ...

Comment: Please correct me if Im wrong, you want to display a dialog when you click the ajaxified button?

Comment: You're right, i want to display my generated form in a modal (currently it's displayed directly on the page in a wrapper) after the callback returned it.

Answer (score 0):

a simpler approach might be to include the form in a custom block, and set it's css to match the modal design you want but set the initial block display to `none`.  Then use an onclick to show the block using whatever transition you want